# How to show only clicked tasks

Tags: reactjs

When I press show subtask, I want only the pressed task and subtasks to appear. When I press the hide button, I want it to return to its old appearance. how can I do that.
[view of the list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ExgtZ.png)

```
return (
    <ListGroup>
        {todos.map((task, index) => (
            <ListGroup key={index} >
                <ListGroupItem style={{ textDecoration: completeTask(task) ? 'line-through' : 'none'}} >
                    {index + 1}....{task.name}....( {task.subdata.length} subtasks )
                    <Button size='sm' className='mx-2' variant='outline-dark' onClick={() => { openClick(task.name) }}>
                        Show Subtasks
                    </Button>
                    <Button size='sm' variant='outline-secondary' onClick={closeClick}>
                        Hide Subtasks
                    </Button>
                </ListGroupItem>
                {task.subdata.filter(child => child.complete === false).map((child, index) => (
                    <ListGroupItem style={{ textDecoration: child.complete ? 'line-through' : '', display: open === task.name ? 'block' : 'none' }} key={index} className='mx-1'>
                        {child.name}
                        <Button size='sm' className='mx-5' variant='outline-dark' onClick={() => { handleToggle(child.id, taskName) }}>
                            {<BsCheckLg  />}
                        </Button>
                    </ListGroupItem>
                ))}
                <ListGroupItem style={{ fontWeight: 'bold', display: open === task.name ? 'block' : 'none' }} className='mx-2'>
                    Completed Subtasks
                </ListGroupItem>

                {task.subdata.filter(child => child.complete === true).map((child, index) => (
                    <ListGroupItem style={{ textDecoration: child.complete ? 'line-through' : '', display: open === task.name ? 'block' : 'none' }} key={index} className='mx-2'>
                        {child.name}
                        <Button size='sm' className='mx-5' variant='outline-dark' onClick={() => { unHandleToggle(child.id, taskName) }}>
                        {<BsXLg  />}
                        </Button>
                    </ListGroupItem>
                ))}
            </ListGroup>
        ))}
    </ListGroup>
)
```

}

Answer (score 0):

It's really difficult to understand what you're trying to achieve exactly but I guess you can use `useState` so that whenever you show or hide it, you set its state the way you want:

```
import { useState } from 'react'
.......

const [visibility, setVisibility] = useState(false)

const openClick = (taskName) => {
  .......
  setVisibility(true)
}

const closeClick = () => {
  .......
  setVisibility(false)
}
```

Comment: style={{display: visibility ? "none" : "block"}}  When I do what you say, only the sub-tasks appear, the parent task disappears.

Comment: Where are you putting `style={{display: visibility ? "none" : "block"}}`?

Comment: >`<ListGroup>
        {todos.map((task, index) => (
            <ListGroup key={index} >
                <ListGroupItem style={{ textDecoration: completeTask(task) ? 'line-through' : 'none', display: visibility ? "none" : "block"}} `    i putted there second listgroup

Comment: I think you should set `display` to `block` when `visibility` is true: `style={{display: visibility ? "block" : "none"}}` You seem to be doing it in reverse.